# How to solve fails which are not reported in console

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, allocation

Maybe it is silly question, but I have an curious problem. My app fails every time I try to refresh my data in database using core data when I re-enter the view controller. If I enter the view controller and refresh data from internet it works. However, when I start the program, enter the view controller, then pop it and re-enter and try refresh data, it fails and nothing is logged in view controller. I do not know why it happens. So I tried to debug it but the problem disappeared. After I tried again without debug mode it failed once more. I do not know why. Could it be problem of allocation, or something not released? Here's my implementation of `-viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    if (managedObjectContext_ == nil) 
    { 
        managedObjectContext_ = [[(NavTestAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext] autorelease]; 
    }

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    [addButton release];

    prikazDatabaseArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]retain];

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
    datumOd = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:now] retain];

    [dateFormatter release];

    VObrat = YES;
}
```

I also use

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool;
NSURLConnection *theConnection;
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest;
NSData *xmlData;
NSData *xmlFile;
NSXMLParser *addressParser;
```

in my code. If you could, at least help me find where I have the problem, because without  debug and console I feel like a blind man.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are creating your own pool then you need to release the pool in the same context or method or loop.

you should use [pool drain] for that.

if you are not able to see your crash log you run with performance tool it will give you the location where u are doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

remove the autorelease from the line `managedObjectContext_ = [[(NavTestAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext] autorelease];`

You didn't retain, so you should not (auto)release it.

---

Edit: I see, there's more.

remove the retain in `prikazDatabaseArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]retain];`. Alloc retains your object already. No need to do it twice.

And get rid of the autoreleasepool or drain it at the end of the method.

You should consider to read the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) again.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, now i know where i made mistakes, but it is still not clear why i could not use debug...or why it is working well while i debug it.and also why it does not make any log in  console?but thanks once again, i vote up your answer but i will wait for the answer which answers my question:How to solve fails which are not reported in console?thanks